# Javascript cannot unhide element after cloning?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, asynchronous

I'm working on something where multiple functions will add various Event listeners to an initially hidden div, let's just call it `secretBlock`. Only one will ever be active at any given point, but all said functions will manipulate it by:

- First cloning `sercetBlock` to ensure no previous listeners are still attached
- Then setting the display to `flex`

HTML:

```
<div id="secretBlock" hidden>Secret</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function exampleFuction() {
    var secretBlock = document.getElementById('secretBlock');
    var secretClone = secretBlock.cloneNode(true);
    secretBlock.parentNode.replaceChild(secretClone, secretBlock);
    secretBlock.style.display = 'flex';
    ....
 }
```

but the last part, setting the display, is not firing.

I assumed this had something to do with async-ness, but

```
setTimeout(function(){ secretBlock.style.display = 'flex' }, 999);
```

also had no effect.

**However**, one of the functions appends the div inside of another div right after setting the display, causing it to fire properly:

```
secretBlock.parentNode.replaceChild(secretClone, secretBlock);
secretBlock.style.display = 'flex';
otherDiv.appendChild(secretBlock);
```

After a bit of testing, I found out it doesn't matter when I set the display (now vs later) or where it is in the code, as long as `secretBlock` gets appended to another div, the display change will register, otherwise staying hidden.

.......which sorta left me clueless as to what's going on, any insight would thus be much appreciated~~

Comment: It's not hidden, it is not a part of the document, because you remove  secretBlock here from the document:  `secretBlock.parentNode.replaceChild(secretClone, secretBlock);`

Comment: @Dr.Molle I added a return right after that to check, but chrome says its still there? Though the element does flash suggesting a change.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Was a reference issue.
After `.replaceChild()`  replaces `secretBlock`, the initial reference:

```
var secretBlock = document.getElementById('secretBlock')
```

becomes obsolete as it still points to the old, original element which is not apart of the html document anymore. Thus you need to redirect the reference to the cloned element:

```
secretBlock.parentNode.replaceChild(secretClone, secretBlock);
secretBlock = document.getElementById('secretBlock');
secretBlock.style.display = 'flex';
```

Thanks [Dr.Molle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/459897/dr-molle)!